# Let's Encrypt SSL Causing Issue with Chrome

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have multiple sites on my host using Let's Encrypt and all of them have had no issues. Today I'm trying to install a certificate on `joescottocpa.com`. The certificate will install but when I visit the site it gives me a `Your connection is not private` error. When I inspect the certificate it says that it is valid.

I'm able to go to the actual `HTTPS` address with no issues. When I type just the domain `joescottocpa.com`in it will sometimes work without issues, sometimes give me the error, and other times just redirect me to my hosting providers homepage.

I am using an `.htaccess` file to redirect the page, the code on the file is the exact same that I've used for every other site that uses `HTTPS`. Any help at all would be great.

Thanks!

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://joescottocpa.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: `curl: (60) Peer's Certificate has expired.`

Comment: It looks like you're load balancing across two machines, perhaps you only installed the cert on one?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm looking at it now and I have a couple domains for `joescottocpa.com`. Most look like this `joescottocpa.placeholdername.com`. I tried adding certificates to them earlier but still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my host. Something with their settings was off that they wouldn't tell me. Needless to say this host caused issues before so I decided to switch to a new host and the issue was no longer there.